# Show that an abelian group $G$ of order 55 must be cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I know that in order to be cyclic: A group G is called cyclic if there exists an element g in G such that G = ⟨g⟩ = { $g^n$ | n is an integer } by wikipedia. But I just get lost in how simple it looks in terms of if we let n=1, then generate everything right?

Comment: Because $55$ is the product of two distinct primes, all the non-trivial subgroups are Sylow. $G$ being abelian implies that there is a unique subgroup of order $5$ and a unique subgroup of order $11$. Thus there are $55-11-5+1=40$ elements that don't belong to any proper subgroup. Each and every one of thems thus has to generate all of $G$, so $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't let $n$ be something, that $n$ is part of the description of the group: $\{g^n | n \text{ an integer}\}$ is notation for the set

$$ \{ ..., g^{-3}, g^{-2}, g^{-1}, e, g, g^2, g^3, ... \}.$$

That means the set of *all* elements of the form $g^n$, not just one particular $n$. It's generated by $g$, not just any $g^n$.

You have to show that if a group is abelian and has $55$ elements, it has to be of that form, i.e. there has to be an element of the group such that every other element is a power of it.

One way to do it is to show that since $55=11\cdot 5$, there has to be an element $g$ of order $11$, and another element $h$ of order 5. Then show that $k=gh$ has to have order $55$, and so $\{k^n | n\text{ is an integer}\}$ is the entire group.

It's not hard to show $k^{55}$ has to be the identity element, so one has to show $k^r$ is the identity only if $r$ is a multiple of $55$. Suppose $k^r=e$, then we have $e= k^r=(gh)^r = g^r h^r$ since the group is abelian, which means $g^r = h^{-r}$. Now $g^r$ is in the cyclic group generated by $g$, and $h^{-r}$ is in the group generated by $h$. The element $g^r=h^{-r}$ must then belong to both $\langle g \rangle$ and $\langle h\rangle$. By considering the orders of these groups, you can show this element must be the identity itself. This would then imply that $r$ is divisible both by $5$ and by $11$.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea doesn't make sense.  A group is cyclic *if* there exists an element $g\in G$ for which every element $h\in G$ has $h= g^n$ for some number $n$.  You don't get to pick $n$ and you don't get to just decide that it is 1; it will be different depending on which element $h$ you are trying to make from $g^n$.

Consider for example the group consisting of $\{1, 2, 4, 8\}$ with multiplication taken modulo 15.  The group is generated by the element $2$, because:  $$\begin{align}
1 & = 2^4\pmod{15}\\
2 & = 2^1\pmod{15}\\
4 & = 2^2\pmod{15}\\
8 & = 2^3\pmod{15}\\
\end{align}$$

with $n$ here being $4, 1, 2, $ or $3$ repsectively.  (The group is also generated by $8$, but not by $4$.)

*If* you wanted to use this, the proof would look like this:

1. You are going to show that there is some $g$, so that for every $h\in G$, there is $n$ for which $g^n = h$.
2. You figure out *one* specific element $g$ which you claim generates $G$.
3. You suppose that someone given you an element $h\in G$.
4. You show how to find $n$ for which $g^n = h$, you can choose a different $n$ depending on what $h$ is, but you don't get to change $g$.

Picking $n=1$ won't work, because in step 3 the other person might give you some $h$ that is not equal to the $g$ you picked in step 2. The $n$ you pick in step 4 will depend on the $h$ you are given in step 3.

Do you know the classification theorem for abelian groups, the one that says that any abelian group must factor into a direct product $\Bbb Z_{p^i}\times \Bbb Z_{q^j}\times\cdots$ where $p, q\ldots $ are prime? That is what I would use to solve this exercise.

Comment: Classification although not hard to prove is slightly overdoing things!

Comment: I agree with MJD-that's how I'd do it,too.

Answer (score 1):

The abelian groups of size 55 up to isomorphism are just the single direct product Z5 X Z11 since that is the only way that 55 can be factored into primes. Since 5 and 11 are relatively prime Z5 X Z11 is cyclic and hence all abelian groups of size 55 are cyclic.

Comment: This is correct, but typically in a group theory course such questions are posed and solved in more elementary terms before one proves the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, which this answer relies on.

Answer (score 0):

The order of any element of the group divides $55$. So the order of an element $\ne e$ is either $5$, $11$, or $55$. We'll show that there are elements of order $55$. Any such element will generate the group and hence the group is cyclic.

First, a basic fact. Let $p$ a prime number and $G$ a finite  abelian group such that $g^p=e$ for all $g \in G$. Then the order of $G$ is a power of $p$. Indeed, $G$ can be considered as a vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p$. Let $d = \dim_{\mathbb{Z}/p} G$. Then $|G|= p^d$.

Using the above result and the previous observation it follows that there exists an element of order $55$ ( we are done then) or there exist two elements $g$, $h$ of orders $5$ and $11$ respectively. We claim that the order of $gh$ is $55$. Indeed $(gh)^{55} = g^{55} \cdot h^{55} = e\cdot e = e$ so its order divides $55$. It cannot be $1$ since $g \ne h^{-1}$, being of different orders, and it's neither $5$ nor $11$. For instance 
$$(gh)^{11}= g^{11} \cdot h^{11} = g \ne e$$

To show that the hypothesis "abelian" is necessary we present an
example of a non-abelian group of order 
$55$ (the other group of order $55$) :

$G$ is a group of the affine transformations of $\mathbb{Z}/11$,

$$T_{a,b} \colon x \mapsto a\cdot x + b$$

where $b \in \mathbb{Z}/11$ and $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/11^{\times})^2= \{1,3,4,5,9\} 
\ \text{mod} 11$

For these kind of examples we used $5 | (11-1)$. It turns out that $\it{any}$ group of order $p\cdot q$ where $p<q$ primes and $p \not | (q-1)$ is cyclic.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: But it was not what asked

Comment: This should be community wiki.